# JQuery doesnt work on content loaded into popover using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, popover

I have a button that is responsible for displaying a users pending friend requests on click. When the button is clicked it triggers a popover which is filled with a feed of pending friend requests using ajax.I got this far without any problems, but for some reason I cant get any jquery to work on the ajax/popover content. So I have 2 questions :

1. Is there some special trick to getting jquery to work on content loaded using ajax that wasnt there when when the page is initially loaded?
2. If your loading content into a popover as i am where should I place the link to the .js file that contains the jquery i would like triggered when a user presses a button inside the ajax/popover? Does it go in the parent or the child file that is being loaded via ajax when the friend request button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

As your content is added dynamically so it is not accessible directly ,So you have to use Event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click','#somelement',function(){

});
```

Syntax

```
$('ParentSelectorPresentAtDOMReady').on('Events','SelectorsOnWhichYouWantToAddEvents(LoadedByAjax)',function(){
      //code here
});
```

You can load all your scripts at DOM ready in head section.

Comment: so your saying if in the head i add : 


$(document).on('click','#somelement',function(){

});




it should work, correct? bc it doesn't at all as of now :/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mydiv").change(function(){
    /*code*/
});
```

becomes

```
$(window).on("change", "#mydiv", function(){
    /*code*/
});
```

or

```
$("#mydiv").click(function(){
   /*code*/
});
```

becomes

```
$(window).on("click", "#mydiv", function(){
   /*code*/
});
```

etc...

As for question #2, you put the library link in the same place as you would in a non-AJAX environment

Comment: the second part makes 0 sense lol....just answer does it go in the parent that is initially loaded or the ajax loaded child?

Comment: is window actually a useable param?